# Setting a prompt in an ABPeoplePickerNavigationController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, abpeoplepickerview

I'm having trouble getting this code to set the prompt:

```
// Create a PeoplePicker
ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *objPeoplePicker = [[ABPeoplePickerNavigationController alloc] init];
[objPeoplePicker setPeoplePickerDelegate:self];

// Customize colors
objPeoplePicker.topViewController.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.294 green:0.278 blue:0.247 alpha:1.0];
objPeoplePicker.topViewController.searchDisplayController.searchBar.tintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.294 green:0.278 blue:0.247 alpha:1.0];

// Only display phone numbers
NSArray *displayedItems = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithInt:kABPersonPhoneProperty], nil];
objPeoplePicker.displayedProperties = displayedItems;

// Add a prompt
objPeoplePicker.navigationBar.topItem.prompt = @"Choose a contact to...";

// Show the picker
[self presentModalViewController:objPeoplePicker animated:YES];
```

The "Add a Prompt" section doesn't seem to be setting the prompt. Any ideas? Here's a screenshot of the output:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key piece of information to this question, and not quite obvious, is that you need to set the prompt **after** the line:

```
[self presentModalViewController:objPeoplePicker animated:YES];
```

So, if you do it like this, it works:

```
[self presentModalViewController:objPeoplePicker animated:YES];
objPeoplePicker.navigationBar.topItem.prompt = @"Choose a contact to...";
```